# R: Shiny - How to subset and then make a bargraph based on daterangeInput

Tags: r, shiny

i've this data frame:

```
    date      sessions      Fuentes
1 2014-12-01      197       Directo
2 2014-12-01        1       Referencias
3 2014-12-01        7       Social Media
4 2014-12-01       13       SEO
5 2014-12-01        1       Email
6 2014-12-01        1       Referencias
```

This is the data after using dput():

```
 structure(list(date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 
29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 
29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 
29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 
29L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L), .Label = c("2014-12-01", 
"2014-12-02", "2014-12-03", "2014-12-04", "2014-12-05", "2014-12-06", 
"2014-12-07", "2014-12-08", "2014-12-09", "2014-12-10", "2014-12-11", 
"2014-12-12", "2014-12-13", "2014-12-14", "2014-12-15", "2014-12-16", 
"2014-12-17", "2014-12-18", "2014-12-19", "2014-12-20", "2014-12-21", 
"2014-12-22", "2014-12-23", "2014-12-24", "2014-12-25", "2014-12-26", 
"2014-12-27", "2014-12-28", "2014-12-29", "2014-12-30", "2014-12-31"
), class = "factor"), sessions = c(197L, 1L, 7L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 
10L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 566L, 1L, 27L, 159L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 10L, 129L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 
1L, 28L, 1L, 7L, 386L, 1L, 146L, 1L, 89L, 41L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
6L, 3L, 4L, 182L, 1L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 524L, 4L, 26L, 1L, 152L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 
10L, 142L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 13L, 3L, 
375L, 3L, 2L, 147L, 1L, 101L, 29L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 224L, 3L, 12L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 141L, 
4L, 632L, 2L, 2L, 32L, 1L, 138L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 139L, 4L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 8L, 36L, 1L, 
537L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 174L, 1L, 106L, 39L, 9L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 689L, 1L, 14L, 2L, 2L, 35L, 1L, 15L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 20L, 465L, 1L, 3269L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 32L, 6L, 2L, 
293L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 11L, 2L, 1L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
7L, 2L, 433L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 19L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 37L, 10L, 88L, 6L, 1808L, 5L, 4L, 451L, 5L, 219L, 
112L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 10L, 2L, 264L, 8L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 17L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 516L, 1L, 948L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 33L, 1L, 1L, 133L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 11L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 6L, 10L, 5L, 168L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 8L, 3L, 98L, 1L, 548L, 1L, 1L, 177L, 97L, 17L, 4L, 
1L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 235L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 2L, 
19L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 396L, 1209L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
41L, 1L, 125L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 
2L, 121L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 10L, 3L, 75L, 
5L, 632L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 178L, 1L, 67L, 33L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 12L, 3L, 194L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 20L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 296L, 1L, 1L, 979L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 33L, 1L, 
109L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 118L, 
1L, 1L, 15L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 18L, 6L, 53L, 3L, 
584L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 172L, 2L, 100L, 27L, 9L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 11L, 3L, 202L, 6L, 20L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 292L, 
719L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 29L, 106L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
7L, 3L, 139L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 17L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 20L, 53L, 3L, 
530L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 172L, 113L, 23L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 
891L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1312L, 
1L, 1L, 1168L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 39L, 133L, 3L, 13L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 13L, 3L, 297L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 25L, 182L, 1L, 776L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 260L, 2L, 115L, 52L, 
14L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 14L, 
2L, 731L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 16L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 11L, 6L, 294L, 
1L, 1135L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 36L, 1L, 1L, 126L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 355L, 3L, 9L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
13L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 22L, 5L, 67L, 1L, 2L, 926L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 208L, 1L, 1L, 136L, 44L, 12L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 198L, 1L, 8L, 13L, 2L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 205L, 568L, 1L, 1L, 19L, 94L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 157L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 28L, 3L, 444L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 118L, 2L, 75L, 27L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 166L, 1L, 1L, 11L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 203L, 644L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 26L, 1L, 
4L, 75L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 155L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 36L, 1L, 2L, 446L, 3L, 1L, 99L, 86L, 
27L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 
1L, 7L, 159L, 1L, 3L, 12L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 174L, 733L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 22L, 2L, 84L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
100L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 8L, 3L, 38L, 7L, 502L, 2L, 1L, 86L, 6L, 
83L, 24L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 321L, 8L, 11L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 13L, 191L, 1L, 5L, 1417L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 28L, 2L, 1L, 
150L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 218L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 16L, 4L, 45L, 1L, 
3L, 879L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 207L, 2L, 115L, 44L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 171L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 
4L, 178L, 614L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 20L, 1L, 94L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 121L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 31L, 1L, 1L, 433L, 1L, 3L, 23L, 94L, 79L, 25L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 160L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 568L, 
1L, 2L, 5L, 15L, 5L, 86L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 118L, 9L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 11L, 3L, 10L, 1L, 530L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 121L, 1L, 1L, 72L, 34L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 
326L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 18L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1271L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 17L, 2L, 161L, 3L, 1L, 14L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 195L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 23L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 20L, 4L, 10L, 1L, 1050L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 19L, 1L, 196L, 134L, 52L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 120L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 371L, 
1L, 1L, 7L, 74L, 2L, 11L, 1L, 3L, 84L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 14L, 2L, 
1L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 382L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 69L, 1L, 54L, 17L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 168L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 5L, 374L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 69L, 1L, 10L, 6L, 85L, 1L, 1L, 
16L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 393L, 3L, 17L, 53L, 75L, 22L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 136L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
488L, 1L, 4L, 25L, 1L, 71L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 126L, 
5L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 445L, 
1L, 1L, 90L, 1L, 77L, 20L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
248L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 981L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 134L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 5L, 194L, 5L, 1L, 16L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 9L, 3L, 8L, 
850L, 1L, 1L, 155L, 1L, 117L, 43L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 124L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 373L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 
1L, 63L, 1L, 2L, 12L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 125L, 7L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 287L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 54L, 1L, 49L, 19L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 91L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
289L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 61L, 1L, 1L, 14L, 2L, 1L, 91L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 241L, 1L, 5L, 42L, 1L, 51L, 9L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 98L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 251L, 1L, 12L, 1L, 47L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 73L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 11L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
214L, 2L, 1L, 40L, 41L, 17L, 3L, 2L, 103L, 1L, 8L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 270L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 21L, 60L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 73L, 4L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 219L, 1L, 55L, 60L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 168L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 404L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 99L, 
3L, 3L, 11L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 115L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 362L, 1L, 2L, 
64L, 2L, 88L, 15L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 104L, 2L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 343L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 10L, 64L, 2L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 106L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 286L, 1L, 2L, 43L, 2L, 56L, 24L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 140L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 479L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 20L, 87L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 118L, 5L, 
1L, 9L, 4L, 1L, 14L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 389L, 1L, 1L, 66L, 1L, 75L, 
13L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 98L, 3L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
341L, 3L, 1L, 21L, 101L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 85L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 278L, 10L, 67L, 2L, 54L, 
15L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 98L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 315L, 1L, 1L, 
6L, 13L, 1L, 59L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 90L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 235L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 53L, 72L, 
18L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 68L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 241L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 9L, 37L, 1L, 1L, 66L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 197L, 47L, 39L, 19L, 1L), Fuentes = structure(c(3L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
7L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
7L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 
5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
7L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 
6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
7L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
7L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 
2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 
5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 
6L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 
5L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
3L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 
1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 
6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
7L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 
7L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 
7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 
7L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 
6L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
7L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 
6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
2L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 
6L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 
1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 
5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 
7L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
7L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 
5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
3L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 
5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Adwords", "Campañas", 
"Directo", "Email", "Referencias", "SEO", "Social Media"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("date", 
"sessions", "Fuentes"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1724L))
```

In a Shiny App, want to plot bars for Fuentes, acording to a data range specified by the user. I use `daterangeInput` in my ui.R, but cannot get it to plot what I need.

My ui.R

```
library(shiny)



# Define the overall UI
shinyUI(

  # Use a fluid Bootstrap layout
  fluidPage(    

    # Give the page a title
     br(),
     br(),
     titlePanel("Visitas por fuente"),

    # Generate a row with a sidebar
     sidebarLayout(      

      # Define the sidebar with one input



       sidebarPanel(
       dateRangeInput("dates", label = h3("Date range"),
                       start = "2014-12-01", end = "2014-12-31")

      ),

      # Create a spot for the barplot
      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("VisitasFuente")  
      )

    )
  )
)
```

My server.R  ### Edited - Now can plot, but labels appeare as a blur from botton to top.

```
 library(ggplot2)
 library(dplyr)
 require(scales)




 Visitas_Por_Fuente <- read.csv("D:\\RCoursera\\Movistar-  App-2\\Visitas_Por_Fuente_Dic.csv")
labels = c("Directo", "Email", "Referencias", "SEO", "Social Media")
Visitas_Por_Fuente$date <- as.Date(Visitas_Por_Fuente$date)





 shinyServer(


  function(input, output) {



output$VisitasFuente <- renderPlot({

  # Filter the data based on user selection month     
  date_seq <- seq(input$dates[1], input$dates[2], by = "day")


  #VisitasData <- filter(Visitas_Por_Fuente, date >= input$dates[1],
  #                     date <= input$dates[2])


  VisitasData <- filter(Visitas_Por_Fuente, date %in% date_seq  & Fuentes %in% labels)

  # Bar graph using ggplot2 library 
  ggplot(VisitasData, aes(factor(Fuentes), sessions, fill = Fuentes)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") +
    geom_text(aes(label = comma(sessions)),  position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25) +
    scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("0", "1", "3", "6", "9"),
                      labels = c("Directo", "Email", "References",
                                 "SEO", "Social Media"),
                      values = c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", 
                                 "#F0E442", "#0072B2"))

})


 })
```

This was fixied by loading the corresponded packages

Thanks to @goodtimeslim, i've made the recomendations you gave me. But now i get:

**Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : 
  'match' requires vector arguments**

What could it be? Thanks again.

#

Comment: can you please `dput`

Comment: @Hack-R i've used dput with my data. It's okay this way? Hope you can help. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, Omar. I just logged back on. Did the answer by goodtimeslim solve your problem? If not, then I will work on a solution for you.

Comment: @Hack-R, thaks to you. Haven't tried that yet. I'll do it when i get home. Let you know what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, first thing, you need to tell R that Visitas_Por_Fuente$date is a date, with `Visitas_Por_Fuente$date <- as.Date(Visitas_Por_Fuente$date)`  .

You can do this right after you import your data at the beginning.
Now you want to create a range of dates, in your server file, using the date inputs, like so:

`date_seq <- seq(input$dates[1], input$dates[2], by = "day")`

Now you just need to change your filter, so that the date is in that sequence, like so:

```
VisitasData <- filter(Visitas_Por_Fuente, date %in% date_seq)
```

Now I admit that doesn't solve everything, I was getting some weird errors with your ggplot code, but this will solve the subsetting issue.

This issue with your ggplot is that your data has 7 variables, but you're only giving it information for 5. If you just want those 5 variables, then at the top (right after you import your data), write this:

```
labels = c("Directo", "Email", "References", "SEO", "Social Media")
```

and then, for your plot, get rid of the scale_manual line and replace it with:

```
scale_x_discrete(limit = labels)
```

That'll force those 5 on there, and at the moment, it'll do it in whatever color R wants. I'll let you figure out the rest if you want to change it.

Let me know if this is clear enough or if you just want the whole server.r code.

edit: Okay, I fixed it. You had an error in your code, you have "References", but in your data, it's "Referencias". So now, assuming you still want those five variables only, and not all 7, do this: change labels (at the top) like so:

```
labels = c("Directo", "Email", "Referencias", "SEO", "Social Media")
```

Change your filter like so:

```
VisitasData <- filter(Visitas_Por_Fuente, date %in% date_seq  & Fuentes %in% labels)
```

Then you can get rid of that `scale_x_discrete` line I had, and put your line back in. It should all work now. (Except edit your labels in the manual_scale part to reflect the proper "Referencias".

edit 2: Here's the full server.r that runs just fine on my computer. I've made some slight changes for consistency/clarity, but otherwise it's mostly the same.

```
library(ggplot2)


Visitas_Por_Fuente <- read.csv("visitas.csv") ## put your path here
labelsF = c("Directo", "Email", "Referencias", "SEO", "Social Media")
Visitas_Por_Fuente$date <- as.Date(Visitas_Por_Fuente$date)





shinyServer(


  function(input, output) {



    output$VisitasFuente <- renderPlot({

      # Filter the data based on user selection month     
      date_seq <- seq(input$dates[1], input$dates[2], by = "day")


      #VisitasData <- filter(Visitas_Por_Fuente, date >= input$dates[1],
      #                     date <= input$dates[2])


      VisitasData <- filter(Visitas_Por_Fuente, date %in% date_seq  & Fuentes %in% labelsF)

      # Bar graph using ggplot2 library 
      ggplot(VisitasData, aes(factor(Fuentes), sessions, fill = Fuentes)) + 
        geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") +
        scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("0", "1", "3", "6", "9"),
                          labels = labelsF,
                          values = c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", 
                                     "#F0E442", "#0072B2"))

    })


  })
```

Comment: Thanks @goodtimeslim. I'll try this at home later. Just one question: Why my subsetting of dates was wrong? Thanks!

Comment: First, R likes ">=", not "=>", and second, I think what's happening is when you read the dataframe in, `date`is being treated like a factor, and can't  compare to a date object that is being passed the shiny ui. When you try it, you get the `warning Incompatible methods ("Ops.Date", "Ops.factor") for ">"`. So `as.date(variable)` will convert variable to a date object.

Comment: i've made the changes suggested by you, but i get this: `Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : 
  'match' requires vector arguments` ... I think is a problem with `%in%`. But can't figure out the solution.

Comment: Okay, I've edited my post to include the full server.r, and it works just fine on my computer. I'm wondering if you have some packages that are out of date or something, because I just copied and pasted your code and it worked fine. Are any of your packages out of date? How old is your R? Try copying and pasting my code (but be sure to fix the path at the  beginning) and see it that works. (I'm expecting it won't, but if it doesn't, then that tells us that something is different between our R's and/or packages).

Comment: Thanks @goodtimeslim, i got it right. I just updated the packages in R, and loaded them in the server.R file, and got what i needed.